# Dramatic slowing down in large List Iterate in java

Tags: java, performance, list, jpa, iteration

I have a Java EE project.
In one EJB, I need to iterate a large List of 35.000 objects.
On each loop, there is comparison in database, and multi insert or update with JPA & EntityManager.

At the begining, it takes about 5 to 7 second to parse 500 lines (acceptable) but gradually it's slowing down. After 10.000 iterations, it takes 26 seconds to process 500 lines ! :

[image: speed slowing down]

I looked on visualVM and I can't find CPU fault or memory leak :

[image: CPU]
[image]

I try to iterate with "classic" for statement, with "for each", Java 8 Stream but the result was the same.

Why is it slowing down ?

Answer (score 0):

I would try to take a shot in dark and say that the database may be your bottleneck.
The more you insert, the more entries does the database have to compare with. Thus there is a possible increase of the time it takes to do that specific task.
Creating table indices may also be a problem in this case.
You may want to break down your task a little bit more, so you could get down to the real bottleneck, but without further information there's no clear answer to that.